# Make standalone class without tikz look like a cropped article

Tags: standalone

How can I force the [standalone](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class to put things on top of eath other instead of next to each other?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
test

test

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways.  As daleif points out, there is a `varwidth` option that allows paragraph breaks.  The default `\textwdith` is `390pt` in this configuration:

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
test

test

test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `varwidth`, one can still proceed.  Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\parbox{\widthof{test}}{%
test

test

test
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want paragraphs of a fixed width, then replace `\widthof{test}` with a fixed length, as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\parbox{7in}{\parindent 1em\relax%
\lipsum[1-3]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another way, useful if the items being stacked are not free-flowing text but individual entities:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Longstack{%
test
test
test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or, for a more complex case,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\stackunder[10pt]{\Longstack[c]{
Happy birthday to you,\\
Happy birthday to you,\\
Happy birthday dear \LaTeX{}\\
Happy birthday to you.
}}{\ldots and many more}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is best will depend on what is being stacked.  Are they single words as you show, or are they free-flowing paragraphs?  Or maybe multi-line phrases with manual line breaks?  Are they centered or left justified? etc. etc. etc. The particular use case will define the best solution.

Comment: Doesn't standalone have a varwidth option that does this automatically?

Comment: @daleif I know there is a `varwidth` option, but don't use `standalone` to know how it works.

Comment: @daleif Thanks.  Edited to include as primary method.